# c# Using Select Linq statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have `Rows` object that is `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, it has 5 properties (columns) and 100 rows.  One of the properties/columns is `Group`, only 2 distinct groups out of 100 rows, so first I run a distinct against it:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> Groups = Rows.Select(x => x.Group).Distinct();
```

This works, no error.

Then I want to go back to my `Rows` object and loop through them where this group = the group in `Rows`, like this:

```
foreach (string Group in Groups)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> GroupData = 
       from rowdata in Rows
       where rowdata.Group = @Group 
       select rowdata;
```

But I get this error on the last line:

```
'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' does not contain a definition for 'Group'
```

Anyone knows why this isn't working?

Surely I can do this another way, but I wanted to use c# select statement instead.  How can I though?

---

Edit to show usage:

```
    foreach (var row in GroupData){
       string ThisGroup = row.Group
    }
     ...
```

Comment: what is `@Group` do you mean to say `where rowdate.Group = "Group"`

Comment: 1) `=` is assignment, not comparison 2) The equivalent of `Rows.Select(x => x.Group)` would be `from x in Rows select x.Group`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you then use GroupData ?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE `@Group` is `Group` in the `foreach` statement. I put a `@` because it's a reserved name in select statements it appears?

Comment: @p.s.w.g So you mean i should do `where rowdata.Group == @Group` ? and first select works, it's the 2nd one giving the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting twice, group on the `Group` value:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, dynamic>> groups = Rows.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Group);
```

Now you can just loop through the result:

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, dynamic> group in groups) {
  ...
}
```

The `IGrouping<>` object has a `Key` property which is the value that you grouped on, and it's also a collection of the values in the group.